# Create a drop down to specify multipliers in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to make an excel sheet where people can input how they spend their time. However, I want to give them different dimensions in which they can spend their time, for example "Hours / day" or "Days / week".

I know already how to create a dropdown via Data validation, but I do not know how to apply a different formula on the field right of the dropdown to make a calculation on the left of the dropdown?

So it should look like this:

[image]

so the user would fill in activities in column A and the time spent on it in Column B, chooses a dimension in Column C and then gets the output in Column D

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *VLOOKUP()* to convert the text into specific multipliers.

In columns **F** and **G**:

[image]

we enter the small lookup table.  *(the 1248 corresponds to [24 hours] x [52 weeks] )*, then in **D2** enter:

```
=B2*VLOOKUP(C2,F$1:G$3,2)
```

and copy down:

[image]